# Isotope grid and inline ajax comments

Tags: css, ajax, comments, inline

I am using the isotope plugin on my site which is in local development. I'm running into a css problem which i'm hoping someone will be able to help me with. Here's the situation.

```
<div class="wrapper"> //* Position is relative
   <div class="portfolio1">  //* Position is absolute
      <div class="inner-wrapper">
         <div class="portfolio-container">
            <div class="portfolio-header"></div>
            <div class="portfolio-content"></div>
            <div class="portfolio-footer">
                <div class="comments"></div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="portfolio2">  //* Position is absolute
      <div class="inner-wrapper">
         <div class="portfolio-container">
            <div class="portfolio-header"></div>
            <div class="portfolio-content"></div>
            <div class="portfolio-footer">
                <div class="comments"></div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="portfolio3">  //* Position is absolute
      <div class="inner-wrapper">
         <div class="portfolio-container">
            <div class="portfolio-header"></div>
            <div class="portfolio-content"></div>
            <div class="portfolio-footer">
                <div class="comments"></div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="portfolio4">  //* Position is absolute
      <div class="inner-wrapper">
         <div class="portfolio-container">
            <div class="portfolio-header"></div>
            <div class="portfolio-content"></div>
            <div class="portfolio-footer">
                <div class="comments"></div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

This pretty much lays the portfolio items out in a grid. My problem is that I have a comment system inside which adds the comments inline. When this happens the ".portfolio" class slides underneath the remaining items on the page. Is there a way either through css or jquery that can remedy this problem? I understand that you can position the elements with relative and float them to keep them from running underneath, but as soon as you do that then the isotope plugin breaks down. Here's a screen shot of the problem as well.
[Screen Shot](http://www.5fifteen.org/Downloads/ScreenS.jpg)
Cheers,
Mike

Comment: It's not clear enough from this where the comments are or what the other items on the page are. Can you post an example?

Comment: Hi Sean,
I just updated the question to give you a better idea.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing the comments are inserted with Ajax? Maybe there's some CSS attached to them that could be overridden to position them differently and keep them within their divs.

Just as likely, though, you shouldn't use Isotope for this. If you're using isotope just to create grid there are simpler ways to do that (you might only need to use `float`). Isotope does some *very* fancy footwork, does it differently in different browsers and really likes to work on elements with a nice, specific size. If the comments are getting added with javascript, changing the divs *at the same as* as Isotope is trying to calculate how it's going to move things around for the layout, you're going to run into trouble.

Comment: Hi Sean,
Yes the comments are being done with Ajax. As soon as the page is refreshed all is well...the problem only occurs when you post the comments without a refresh.

Comment: Also..I'm using Isotope for filtering as well.

Comment: I've seen similar things with isotope (ok on refresh, for example) but it's hard to say anything specific without looking at a live example. What selector are you calling isotope on? Can you delay calling isotope until the comments have loaded since they affect the size of their parents?

Comment: Hi Sean,
It's a template that I bought that I am re-working for our business. Here's a link to the demo. http://www.mojo-themes.com/item/swap-minimal-responsive-wp-portfolio-theme/demo/. That will show you the Isotope stuff. What i'm trying to accomplish is having comments inside of the portfolio item which is actually a custom post type in wordpress.